# Formal proof that the following definitions of perfect secrecy are equivalent

Tags: security-definition, perfect-secrecy, adversarial-model

I've seen the following two definitions of perfect secrecy for an encryption scheme `(Gen, Enc, Dec)`.

1. `Pr[M = m | C = c] = Pr[M = m]` for all c, m, M and C

Intuitively, this means that if the adversary trying to guess the plaintext, gets no information from the ciphertext.

2. `Pr[k <- Gen | Enc k m1 = c] = Pr[k <- Gen | Enc k m2 = c]` for all k, m1, m2, c

Informally, this means that any key `k` encodes both `m1` and `m2` to `c` with equal probability.

Can someone formally show me how these two definitions are in fact, equivalent?

Comment: I believe this is homework. So little hints: if the ciphertext probability is not equal then there is no perfect secrecy! the other similar, if perfect secrecy than it is trivial...

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I'll try answering this myself today. No, it's not homework, but I understand why you think it might be. :D